# Can I somehow combine these two commands into a single one?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have video files in the format of MP4. I need to convert these to MP2. However, when they exceed a certain file size in the MP2 format, I also need to cut them up in smaller files.

For this, I currently have two commands:

Conversion command

```
ffmpeg -i INPUTfile -codec:v mpeg2video -qscale:v 0 OUTPUTfile
```

Cutting command (the time values are just for the example)

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00.00 -i INPUTfile -to 00:10:00.00 -c copy -copyts OUTPUTfile
```

Currently, I convert the video file, check the file size. If it is too big, I will cut up the original video file first, then convert the 'parts' to MP2.

I'm new to ffmpeg and was wondering if I could combine these two commands in one. Again, what I need to do is convert a MP4 file and cut it up. If I do the conversion first and the cut later, or the other way around does not really matter for me.

I will need to run the cutting command multiple times, as i programmatically will decide into how many 'parts' I will cut the file. The end result(s) needs to be in MP2 however, regardless of how many 'parts' I end up with.

Comment: If you are using a constant or average bitrate encoder then file size is a function of time, so you could just set a cap on bit rate and then split based on time. If you are using quality based variable bitrate then it would be very difficult to define exactly how long a time a particular file size would be.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, but I know the times beforehand. I know I want to cut from 0 to 30 mins in for example. What I wonder about is the cut and convert the cut file in once command, if that is an option.

Comment: What about `ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00.00 -i INPUTfile -to 00:10:00.00 -codec:v mpeg2video -qscale:v 0 OUTPUTfile` ? Just a guess, not at a computer I can check on at the moment.

Comment: That seems to work! If you don't mind me asking, could you explain to me why it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your second command is doing the time split then this is the best place to start for "merging" these commands.

You should simply be able to replace the `-c copy -copyts` with the appropriate codec conversion parameters from your first command. These parameters basically mean "just copy the stream as is" while the other time parameters are setting start and stop points. As a result we can change "copy the stream" to "convert the video" from your first command.

The parameters from your first command that relate to the conversion of mp4 to mp2 are `-codec:v mpeg2video -qscale:v 0`. The `codec:v mpeg2video` is telling `ffmpeg` to use the mpeg2video encoder and `qscale` being 0 means "best quality".

At any rate a quick transposition gives you

`ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00.00 -i INPUTfile -to 00:10:00.00 -codec:v mpeg2video -qscale:v 0 OUTPUTfile`

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly and I understand why as well now :)